# Go sendgrid failing

Tags: google-app-engine, go, sendgrid

Im trying to send a mail with sendgrid and golang. 
Im using `"github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go"`

Whenever I run the part sending email in my code, I get this error:

```
sendgrid.go: error:net/http: Client Transport of type init.failingTransport doesn't support CancelRequest; Timeout not supported; response:<nil>
```

I cant figure out what it is..

This is my code:

```
sg := sendgrid.NewSendGridClientWithApiKey("string")
    email := sendgrid.NewMail()
    email.AddTo(req.Email)
    email.SetSubject("Confirm your registration at domain")
    email.SetFrom("noreply@domain.com")
    email.SetFromName("domain")
    email.SetText(url)
    if r := sg.Send(email); r == nil {
        log.Infof(ctx, "email sent")
    } else {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "email not sent %v", r)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
```

Comment: It looks as if you're getting a timeout. Do you get a timeout if you try telneting to port 25 on the mailserver too?

Comment: I cannot telnet to smtp.sendgrid.net with port 25. But I can telnet if im using another port, 587.. Maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Let me rephrase it: if you're getting a timeout error, start by verifying the connection, not the code. I don't know this particular service, so I can't tell you exactly how you should test it - but if you are using SMTP, it's likely that you'll have to tell your application to use 587 instead of 25. If you're using a HTTP/HTTPS API, again, start by verifying connectivity to that port.

Comment: Just to be annoying: It's called *Go* not *golang*.

Comment: Golang for browser friendliness, and yes. It's annoying.

Comment: The go library uses https to talk to sendgrid.  Try to telnet to api.sendgrid.com port 443 to see if you can even connect

Comment: Which Go version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

## Normal Sendgrid API Usage in Go

The minimal program to use the Sendgrid API in Go is something like the following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go"
)

func main() {
    key := "SENDGRID_API_KEY"
    sg := sendgrid.NewSendGridClientWithApiKey(key)

    message := sendgrid.NewMail()
    message.AddTo("ezra@usefultiftrue.com")
    message.SetFrom("test@example.org")
    message.SetSubject("SUBJECT HERE")
    message.SetHTML("BODY OF THE EMAIL")

    if r := sg.Send(message); r == nil {
        fmt.Println("Sent!")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}
```

You can see the [Sendgrid Go Documentation on Github](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go).

## Quirks on App Engine

The issue is that you're attempting to fetch a Url using the default `net/http` client, which is not allowed by App Engine. [You must use `urlfetch` to make `HTTP` requests on App Engine.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/)

You can solve this by specifying your `*http.Client` to use `urlfetch`, since Sendgrid uses a client that uses the disallowed `http.DefaultTransport` by default. `init.failingTransport` is a dummy transport method that basically just throws an error.

This is ultimately a simple change. Simply import `"appengine/urlfetch"` and add

```
client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
```

## A Complete Example of the SendGrid Go API on App Engine

```
package ezralalonde

import (
    "appengine"
    "appengine/urlfetch"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go"
    "net/http"
)

func send(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    key := "SENDGRID_API_KEY"
    sg := sendgrid.NewSendGridClientWithApiKey(key)

    // must change the net/http client to not use default transport
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
    client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)
    sg.Client = client // <-- now using urlfetch, "overriding" default

    message := sendgrid.NewMail()
    message.AddTo("ezra@usefultiftrue.com")
    message.SetFrom("test@example.org")
    message.SetSubject("SUBJECT HERE")
    message.SetHTML("BODY OF THE EMAIL")

    if e := sg.Send(message); e == nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Sent!")
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, e)
    }
}

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", send)
}
```

Now each visit to `/` will cause an email to be sent by SendGrid to `test@example.org`.

```
To: test@example.org
From: ezra@usefuliftrue.com
Subject: SUBJECT HERE

BODY OF THE EMAIL
```

## Please Note

Do not include your API keys in source code, or commit them to your source control. The above method is not advisable.

Comment: I haven't had time to test it. The code is deployed with another solution than sendgrid. I will get back to this whenever I change that solution, and I will do in the future. Many thanks for understanding my problem and offering your solution.

Comment: May I ask who your alternate provider is?

Comment: Absolutely. I'm using Google app engines own mail system. The drawback is that I have to create a separate email user to send from "noreply". But it is even simpler than sendgrid.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! I assume you're 100% transactional, so it's not as big a deal, but I've found that the "dash" and stats that most dedicated mail providers suppliers is something that I never want to be without. Good luck with your app! Cheers,